# Read, sort and split text file into blocks

Tags: php

I am trying to re-activate my php knowledge for the following task:
I have a larger textfile containing unsorted lines of comma separated informations, each value enclosed by a '"'.
Each line can be understood as a single dataset, the first value of the line tells me in which table the row belongs.

Now I need to read the file, sort the lines (so that the lines belonging to the same table are together), detect the different blocks and save them in seperate text files. After that, I can do a fast import into a mysql database using load data from infile..

So, I can open the file and sort the lines via this:

```
<?php
$lines = file("importfile_unsorted.txt");
natsort($lines);
file_put_contents("importfile_sorted.txt", implode($lines));
?>
```

This works. But now I get stucked. importfile_sorted.txt looks like this:

```
"AV1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0:0","0:0","0:0"
"AV2","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0:0","0:0","0:0"
```

.... [this would be the first block, all these lines should be saved in "av.txt"
In the next line the new block "F" begins with several lines:

```
"F1","D","D","Deutsch",,,"0","W"
"F4","E","E","Englisch",,,"0","W"
"F7","K","K","Kath.Religionslehre",,,"0","W"
"F8","Ev","Ev","Evang.Religionslehre",,,"0","W"
"F9","Eth","Eth","Ethik",,,"0","W"
```

... [save all these lines beginning with Fxx into file f.txt and go to the next blocks]

```
"G1","PhL","PÜG"
"G2","ChL","ChÜ"
```

..

```
"K1","5a","5a",,"304","Ma","Wei","0","16","16","5",,,,,"1","1","0",,"0","0","0","0"
"K2","5b","5b",,"303","Wo","Hm","0","32","16","5",,,,,"1","1","0",,"0","0","0","0"
"K3","5c","5c",,"302","Gr","Ro","0","32","16","5",,,,,"1","1","0",,"0","0","0","0"
```

... and so on. Later, there are blocks with a fixed first column like this:

```
"PL","Di 1","Ba","Q12","Inf1","CoR1"
"PL","Di 1","Bb","Q12","F","Ü2"
"PL","Di 1","Eg","Q12","L","M23"
```

...
and

```
"PLS","Di 1","Am"," frei "
"PLS","Di 1","Bad"," ----"
"PLS","Di 1","Bk"," frei "
```

...
followed by several other blocks (L1... L97, M, R1... R40, U1... U560).

I know all possible "identifiers" (AVx, Fx, Gx, .. PL, PLS..) of the blocks, but it is also possible that a block is omitted and the input file does not a single line of it at all. 
The input file contains about 4000 lines all together, so performance should not be too low (although it's not time-critical, the import is done maybe 10 times a year..).

So, is there a way of getting this done in a "smart" and fast way or should I read the input file line by line, detect and remember the first value, add the current line to a result string and loop until a new first value occurs?

Thanks for your help!
Heiko

Comment: Why split the file into separate files? What I would do is create a temp table that has that first column as well, import everything into that. Then use php to query a distinct list of column 1, loop over and just run the query `INSERT INTO {$tableName} SELECT col2, col3...etc FROM tmp_table WHERE col1='{$tableName}'`. If you have variable number of columns per table, just describe each table in php to get the columns and select out only what you need. Also, make the temp table have whatever the largest number of column you need.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your fast answer. I would prefer splitting because importing data into mysql using load data infile is easy and fast, so I am looking for a good way to split the input file. In addition, data types vary between different blocks (for ex. second field in block 1 is int, in block 2 time...).

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn, I finally had the time to follow your suggestion. I thought it would be more complicated, but everything runs smooth and fast, so thank you for pointing me to right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in CSV parser, don't split this manually
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Hm. Ok, this would put the whole input file in one huge array - but I still have to identify the different blocks and save them into seperate text files, right?

Comment: Correct, you use this is parse the data, then begin doing what you will with it.